# Need to convert date format to Chicago tIME ZONE format as In azure data flow explorer expression builder , tried so many bit not useful , example is

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, timestamp-with-timezone, expressionbuilder

I need to convert to csv date column in this format, tried so many in AZURE DATA FACTORY data flow expression builder but nothing works, can someone please help on this. Here for the last 4 digits , it's always  +00:00 is for all the rows from the csv file.

When I try to use this link , getting some what better results. https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters but not in the expression builder

source column value from csv :2023-10-06T07:00:00.000Z

Oracle table column : 9/15/2023 12:00:00.000000 AM **+00:00**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toTimestamp()` function in Azure Data Factory Dataflow Expression Builder to convert the date format to Chicago format.

Add a derived column to the source and use the expression below in the Expression Builder:

```
toTimestamp(<column>, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','CDT')
```

[image]

To get the required format, i.e., `9/15/2023 12:00:00.000000 +00:00`, add a derived column transformation and use the following expression:

```
toString(convertedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss +00:00', "CDT")
```

You will get the output as shown below:

[image]